# Почему происходит ошибка линковки , используя makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

У меня есть 3 файла:

### 1. hellomake.c

```
#include <hellomake.h>

int main() {
  // call a function in another file
  myPrintHelloMake();

  return(0);
}
```

### 2. hellofunc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <hellomake.h>

void myPrintHelloMake(void) {

  printf("Hello makefiles!\n");

  return;
}
```

### 3. hellomake.h

```
/*
example include file
*/

void myPrintHelloMake(void);
```

Все файлы `hellomake.c,hellofunc.c,hellomake.h` хранятся в папке `src`. Я хочу получить объектные .o файлы и сохранить их в папке `obj`, то есть сделать только этап компиляции. (Это нужно мне за тем,чтобы потом их слинковать в статическую библиотеку). Вот так выглядит makefile:

```
CC=gcc

ODIR=obj

_DEPS = hellomake.h 

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(_DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I.

hellomake: $(OBJ)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~
```

Но я ловлю вот такую ошибку:

```
elvin@ubuntu:~/GuideToLinkers/example5/src$ make hellomake 
gcc -c -o obj/hellomake.o hellomake.c -I.
gcc -c -o obj/hellofunc.o hellofunc.c -I.
gcc     hellomake.c obj/hellomake.o obj/hellofunc.o   -o hellomake 
obj/hellomake.o: In function `myPrintHelloMake':
hellomake.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `myPrintHelloMake'
/tmp/ccGYJPJd.o:hellomake.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'hellomake' failed
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1
```

Помогите разобраться, я хочу получить только объектные файлы, поэтому эта строчка  мне не нужна -     `gcc     hellomake.c obj/hellomake.o obj/hellofunc.o   -o hellomake`

Comment: `hellomake: $(OBJ)` в одну строку

Comment: Кстати, для добавления префиксов есть функция `addprefix`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, теперь жалуется на multiple definition elvin@ubuntu:~/GuideToLinkers/example5/src$ make hellomake 
gcc -c -o obj/hellomake.o hellomake.c -I.
gcc -c -o obj/hellofunc.o hellofunc.c -I.
gcc     hellomake.c obj/hellomake.o obj/hellofunc.o   -o hellomake
obj/hellomake.o: In function `myPrintHelloMake':
hellomake.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `myPrintHelloMake'
/tmp/cc37GYPf.o:hellomake.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'hellomake' failed
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1

Comment: Не виду в makefile такой команды

Comment: @AlexeyTen, пробовали запустить? Просто я не понимаю,почему выполняется последняя команда

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @Elvin И в чем было дело?